# How can I deal with the noxious bulbs?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I have a bit of a problem - void salamanders I can't defeat on one side of the hideout in the Hollow Marshes and the noxious bulb traps on the other. I can run through their effect fields and just heal aggressively after, but it'd be a lot nicer if I could destroy them somehow.

I tried having my enchantress cast a few spells and fired a few shots from a crossbow, but the health bars on the bulbs stayed full. Inspecting them turned up the fact that they're at 100% resistance to every damage type. So, is there anything I can do to get rid of them?

Comment: Sounds like they're being... *ob*noxious...

Answer (score 8):

**Either teleport them away or hit them with their own elemental damage type**

You can use either teleport or a character with high telekinesis to displace them and put them somewhere where they are out of the way, or you can disable them: Deal damage directly to them of their corresponding type and they will become disabled, until they are damaged directly by a different elemental damage type.

E.g. for green Bulbs, a poison dart targeted directly at them will disable them, though it will not deplete their health

Comment: This↑ It was actually mentioned in one of the readable books you can pickup from somewhere in fort Joy iirc

Comment: Teleporting them seems to be removed. I haven't been able to target any.

Comment: What skill are you using? MIght be the case, though, it has been some time since I finished the game and I have not touched it since.

Comment: @Patta Just the normal "teleport" skill; although I think I was using the gloves at the time. I'll test again using a memorized teleport; although I wouldn't expect that to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to be undead. Undead are immune to poison and can just walk through the poison clouds. Just unchain your party undead (or get Fane, if you don't have one), let him walk through the poison clouds, activate the waypoint and get the rest of your party.

The other option is to get them out of the way. Use the teleport spell or get telekinesis on a character to move them somewhere, where they don't annoy you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a bedroll to instantly heal**

You mention "healing aggressively" - do you have a bedroll? One click out of combat will fully heal your party. There is a bedroll item near the very beginning of the game, on an overlook/ruined bridge right before you first encounter Dallis and the Fort Joy Proper. This way, you can tank the damage from the clouds and not waste resources topping up or waiting several turns for your Restoration spell to come off of cooldown.

**Use a skill to get up and over**

Other methods to circumvent the bulbs, and certainly many other cloud hazards and the like, are: Teleport (Aerothurge), Tactical Retreat (Marksman), Phoenix Dive (Warfare), and Cloak and Dagger (Scoundrel).

All of these abilities allow your character to either move themself or another object.

**Divinity is flexible - it's up to you**

Personally I took my party through a cloud, ate the damage, and used my bedroll to heal up when I needed to. Later in the game, as well as in my co-op campaign, I have been circumventing many obstacles with Bull Rush (can move you through locked doors you have line of sight through) and Phoenix Dive/Teleport.

Divinity is a diverse, flexible game and I've no doubt the other answers have credence as well. Hitting them with a similar element to disable them does honestly seem like the simplest choice if you have that resource, but not every party has access to every elemental damage type.

Comment: *"There is a bedroll item near the very beginning of the game on an overlook/ruined bridge right before you first encounter Dallis"* Earlier than that, there's two bedrolls on the prisoner ship. They are found near Beast. I'm not sure about map orientation. If you consider the Red Prince north of Beast, then the bedrolls are to the south of Beast

Answer (score 0):

I used two techniques here: the first involved one of my characters being a summoner. I made a minion of the same type as the bulb, and just had them carry it to a corner nearby.

Also, if any of your characters have Telekinesis 2+ you should be able to use that to move the bulbs from a safe distance. If you don't know, just select the character with Telekinesis and drag the bulb where you want to put it.